# Odd results in MS Access Query using a DSUM function and parameters

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I've just started using MS Access this month and I have a very odd bug. I'm trying to create a query that searches for records in a table that have a maxBenefit (a dsum from a different table's field, with a one to many relationship) within a certain range. I'm using the DSUM function to get the maxBenefit because the table has a dailyBenefits field that need to be added together.

Here is my function:

```
maxBenefitOfQuote: Nz(DSum("[wholeYearBenefit]","tblDisabilityQuoteDailyBenefits",
         "[quoteID] = " & [tblDisabilityQuotes].[ID]))
```

I know the function works because it produces the correct values. The query also takes in two parameters from a form to create a range for maxBenefits.

I limit the results with this criteria:

```
>=[Forms]![frmDisabilityFindSimilarQuotes]![minBenefitTotal] And 
<=[Forms]![frmDisabilityFindSimilarQuotes]![maxBenefitTotal]
```

The problem is I get very odd results from the query with maxBenefits outside the range or not returning records with maxBenefits inside the range. If I set the minBenefitTotal to 0 and the max BenefitTotal to 100000000 I get no records returned from the query. If I set the minBenefitTotal to 0 and the maxBenefitTotal to 999999999 I get all the proper records.

Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: The dailyBenefit field is a currency. Could this be a problem? Other fields in question are numeric.

Comment: Can you fix the quotation marks around `[wholeYearBenefit]` ?

Comment: No change unfortunately, hmm..

Comment: Yes, sorry, quotations are correct in code

Comment: Yes that worked... so there's a problem with the numbers I'm pulling from my form fields?

Comment: Yes thank you very much. I used the CCur conversion in vba before running the query and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,

Try wrapping both of your inputs in a call to CCur:

```
>=CCur([Forms]![frmDisabilityFindSimilarQuotes]![minBenefitTotal]) And  
<=CCur([Forms]![frmDisabilityFindSimilarQuotes]![maxBenefitTotal])
```

Next,

If you omit the actual form inputs, and hard-code numbers into the criteria, does it work? 
For Example: (>= 0 and <= 100000000)

If that worked... It feels like a string -> number conversion issue. Make sure all string input is actually a number (via `CCur()`) before sending it into the query.